# Perl not printing the special characters

Tags: html, perl, xpath, perl-module

My scrape content is not displaying the special characters.It shows some junk values in place of special characters.(€  printed as -aA).Thanks in advance.

```
#  !/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => "Mozilla/5.0");
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'http://www.infanziabimbo.it/costi-modalita-e-tempi-di-spedizione.html');
my $res = $ua->request($req);

die("error") unless $res->is_success;

my $xp = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($res->content);
my @node =  $xp->findnodes_as_strings('//div[@class="mainbox-body"]');
die("node doesn't exist") if $#node == -1; # Line 18
open HTML, ">C:/Users/jeyakuma/Desktop/kjk.html";
foreach(<@node>)
{

print HTML "$_";


}
close HTML;


"
```

Comment: See [perlunicode](http://p3rl.org/perlunicode) and [Encode](http://p3rl.org/Encode).

Comment: What encoding does "it" expect?

Comment: Do you get a *"Wide character in print"* warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some observations on your code that I hope will help you

- You must always check that a call to `open` succeeded, otherwise your program will just continue to run silently without any input or output. Rather than the idiomatic `open ... or die $!` you may prefer just to add `use autodie` at the top of your code
- If the HTTP request fails, it is more informative if your program indicates *why* it failed instead of just saying *"error"*. I suggest you write this instead

  ```
  $res->is_success or die $res->status_line;
  ```
- If you don't need any special LWP or parse options, then you can just write

  ```
  my $url = 'http://www.infanziabimbo.it/costi-modalita-e-tempi-di-spedizione.html';
  my $xp  = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_url($url);
  ```

  although that doesn't give you any way to specify the user agent string as you do currently
- Rather than testing `$#node` for equality to -1, it is much neater to check for the *truth* of `@node`, so

  ```
  die "node doesn't exist" unless @node; # Line 18
  ```
- If your data contains UTF-8 characters then your output file handle must be set to the appropriate mode. You can change the mode using `binmode`, like this

  ```
  open HTML, ">C:/Users/jeyakuma/Desktop/kjk.html";
  binmode HTML, ':encoding(utf-8)';
  ```

  But the best way is to use the preferred three-parameter form of `open`, which would look like this, assuming that you have `use autodie` in place at the start of your program

  ```
  open HTML, '>:encoding(utf-8)', 'C:/Users/jeyakuma/Desktop/kjk.html';
  ```
- Lexical file handles are far superior to the old-fashioned global file handles
- The loop `foreach(<@node>) { ... }` is completely wrong because it is equivalent to `foreach (glob join ' ', @node) { ... }` and only appears to work because, in general, `glob` will leave a filename untouched if it doesn't contain any wildcards. What you meant was just `for (@node) { ... }`
- In addition, it is bad practice to enclose a variable in quotes unless you specifically want to call its stringification method, so `"$_"` should be just `$_`
- You may as well write your final output loop as

  ```
  print HTML @node;
  ```

Putting these changes in place, the result looks like this, which I believe will fix your problem

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $url = 'http://www.infanziabimbo.it/costi-modalita-e-tempi-di-spedizione.html';
my $xp  = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_url($url);

my @node = $xp->findnodes_as_strings('//div[@class="mainbox-body"]');
die "node doesn't exist" unless @node;

open my $html_fh, '>:encoding(utf-8)', 'C:/Users/jeyakuma/Desktop/kjk.html';
print $html_fh @node;
close $html_fh;
```

Comment: I hope he needs UTF-8 as you guessed, but he might be expecting cp1252. If so, change `:encoding(UTF-8)` to `:encoding(cp1252)`.

Comment: @ikegami -Yes as u guessed cp1252 is working fine with the code Thanks a lot !

Comment: @borodin: Hi Thanks for your help.I have array of urls to check and if one url gets failed either by "node fail" or "url fail" that has to be recorded in log.html and that should not affect other urls process.

Comment: @user3768218: It sounds like you have a new problem, so you should open a new question. It may help if you refer back to this question